# Probability of getting exactly one ace and exactly one king in your opening hand.

Tags: probability

In a 52 cards deck, what is the probability of getting exactly one ace and exactly one king in your openning hand (5 cards)?

At first I was calculating the odds like this:

5C2 (44/52) (43/51) (42/50) (4/49) (4/48) = 0.04

But then I realized I have 3 types of cards, aces, kings and non-aces/non-kings. So I'm not sure I can use the binomial factor in this exercise.

Thanks

Comment: You are right, you can't use the binomial coefficient because there are 3 types. In alphabetic form, you are choosing AAABC, so  you can use the *multinomial* coefficient, $\binom{5}{3,1,1}$ which is the same as the permutations of such a word, $\frac{5!}{3!1!1!}$

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Exactly 1 Ace could be picked in ${4\choose1}$ ways, similarly exactly 1 King could be picked in ${4\choose1}$.  Now you have 8 cards removed from the deck and the remainder 3 cards should come from 44 cards which are non - ace and non-king.  That you can choose in ${44\choose3}$.  Lastly, 5 cards could be chosen in ${52\choose5}$

Thus the probability is $$\approx \dfrac{{4\choose1}.{4\choose1}.{44\choose3}}{{52\choose5}}$$

EDIT:

Other way is :

The Ace could be chosen with a probability $= \frac{4}{52}$

The King could be chosen with a probability $= \frac{4}{51}$

Rest of the three cards could be chosen with a probability  $= \frac{44}{50}.\frac{43}{49}
.\frac{42}{48}$

These five cards could be picked in $=\frac{5!}{1!.1!.3!}  $

Now multiply $$=\frac{4}{52}.\frac{4}{51}.\frac{44}{50}.\frac{43}{49}
.\frac{42}{48}.\frac{5!}{1!.1!.3!}$$

The first method is an approximate where as the second one is the most accurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it now but, can this be expressed as my original post? I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out. I mean. I understand your reasoning but I can't express the procedure in a different way.

Comment: I just edited it, I did not realize that up until now the first method is usually an approximate solution where is the the second one is the right method that takes into account without replacement which might playout to be diferent in other problems.  In this problem it is exact

Comment: I just edited before I looked at your comment just for the integrity sake. Of course I had wrongly typed it.

Comment: Fine, I have deleted my earlier comment. However, It is not only in *this* problem that the first method is exact, you will find that it is so in all such problems.

Comment: @true blue anil Take an example:  A standard 52-card deck contains cards of 4 suits and 13 numbers, with exactly one card for each pairing of suit and number. If Maya draws two cards with replacement from this dec
k, what is the probability that the two cards have the same suit or have the same number, but not both?  The exact answer is 15/52.

Comment: @true blue anil (contd..) After drawing the first card, there are 12 other cards from the same suit and 3 other cards with the same number, so the probability is $\frac{12+3}{52}$.  This could be also solve $\dfrac{4.{13\choose2}+13.{4\choose2}}{{52\choose2} }= \frac{5}{17}$ which is slightly different than the previous result

Comment: My comment was for  the type of problem given: a hypergeometric distribution which draws w/o replacement from disjoint sets.

Comment: No Problem, if the counting problem becomes huge and the sample is small compared to all outcomes, then the difference to account for without replacement  and using choose calculation to compute becomes negligible and hence the difference.  By the bye, I must guess you are a student somewhere in India.  Thanks for noticing the error.

Comment: @satishramanathan Why is the first method considered to be just an estimation and not exact? I get exactly the same answers both ways. Can you explain this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a hypergeometric distribution (drawing w/o replacement)

I would prefer to solve it using combinations for choosing from the $3$ distinct groups

$Pr = \dfrac{\binom41\binom41\binom{48}3}{\binom{52}5}$

Your attempt will give the same answer if you use the appropriate multinomial coefficient as noted against your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I understand the logic behind the procedure now.